I need to fetch data like How many CPUs and RAM is being utilized in Virtual machines using resource graph explorer
resources| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend Size = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize)
| extend CPUs = toint(extract(".+\[A-Z\](\[0-9\]+).+", 1, tostring(Size)))
| extend RamSize = tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.diskSizeGB)
| extend RamSizeGB = toint(extract("(\[0-9\]+)", 1, RamSize))
| extend VMName = name
| where CPUs > 1
| project VMName, Size, CPUs, RamSizeGB

I am using his query, but this is not correct way as it regex from size type and RAM is also not coming, it is fetching disk size instead of RAM.

Hi @Khushboo Chandak, Are you looking for the VM's RAM size?

There is no separate property for CPU and RAM in the JSON, so it is not possible to directly fetch available CPU and RAM using a Resource Graph query. However, this can be achieved through Log Analytics.

@VenkatV how can we do it using log analytics ?

Hi @KhushbooChandak, Posted a solution with detailed steps. Kindly check and confirm whether it's helpful or not.


I need to fetch data like How many CPUs and RAM is being utilized in Virtual machines using resource graph explorer.

AFAIK, since there is no way to monitor live metrics using Resource Graph Explorer, you can obtain the same information via DCR
Here are the detailed steps to fetch the same information using LAW.

Create a Log analytics workspace

Once you create the Log Analytics Workspace, you can then create a Data Collection Rule with your virtual machine resources.




Configure the data source and destination as shown in the image below



Once all configurations are complete, wait for some time (about 10 minutes) for the current metrics to sync to LAW.

Run the query below in the Log Analytics Workspace by navigating to LAW > Logs.


Perf
| where ObjectName == "Processor Information" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total"
| summarize 
    AVG_CPU_Used = avg(CounterValue), 
    MAX_CPU_Used = max(CounterValue) 
    by Computer, _ResourceId
| join kind=inner (
    Perf  
    | where ObjectName == "Memory" 
    | where CounterName == "Available Bytes" or CounterName == "% Committed Bytes In Use" or CounterName == "Committed Bytes"
    | summarize 
        AvailableRAM_In_GB = avgif(CounterValue, CounterName == "Available Bytes") / (1024 * 1024 * 1024),  // Convert Available Bytes to GB
        RAM_In_Use_Percent = avgif(CounterValue, CounterName == "% Committed Bytes In Use") 
    by Computer
    | extend TotalRAM_In_GB = AvailableRAM_In_GB / (1 - (RAM_In_Use_Percent / 100)) // Calculate Total RAM based on Available RAM and RAM usage percentage
) on Computer
| project Computer, AVG_CPU_Used, MAX_CPU_Used, AvailableRAM_In_GB, RAM_In_Use_Percent, TotalRAM_In_GB, _ResourceId
| order by Computer asc


Output:

Reference: Create and edit data collection rules (DCRs) and associations in Azure Monitor
Create a Log Analytics workspace
